# Using Windows Workflow Foundation in Windows Service for remote execution of workflow

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am investigating how to host WF in a Windows Service and at the same time being able to communicate with the WF mechanism in the Windows Service from other applications instructing it to execute workflow available as xaml on the disk. The WF mechanism needs to be able to run workflows in parallel.

Anything I should be aware of?
Any suggestion on what good articles that would be helpful?
Any examples out there that I would borrow from :-) ?

Best Regards 
Franz Thomsen

Comment: It's a common pattern.  You should 1) use a search engine to find links and articles 2) prototype

Comment: Yes, and since it is a common pattern, I am sure there are also people with experience in what works and what doesn't. And that's what I am looking for.

Comment: Actually ... if it is such a common pattern, perhaps you can point me in the direction on information on how I ask a service to execute a specific workflow from disk using parameters supplied in the request. As far as I can see, its the instance of the workflow itself that waits for the arguments with a Recieve activity, but thats kind of the hen and the egg issue here as it does not know what to execute

Comment: @FranzThomsen from your comments I would suggest that you look into a WCF service hosted as a windows service. This can expose endpoints that can be called with various parameters that will allow the logic within your WCF layer to hydrate xaml files from disk and execute them. If you require a basic example I can reply with one.

Comment: @DotNetHitMan ..... Ok. From the "official" examples I have been looking at that comes with WF+WCF I haven't seen that approach, and thats probably why I am a bit blank as it seems a workflow actually has to be started to begin listening for requests to run it (may very well be mistaken though). A basic example to get my bearings would be absolutely fantastic :-) Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments to your question, one option is to use WCF to host an endpoint that when invoked will execute your workflow.

As a basic example create a simple WCF layer. The endpoint here accepts 2 params to show you an example of passing a param to WCF and onto the WF. It then creates a WF application that re-hydrates the .xaml file and executes it.

```
using System;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.XamlIntegration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace WCFForWorkflowsExample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// basic WCF layer - added references to System.Activities and System.Xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// create a thread blocking event to allow the wf enough time to complete.
        /// </summary>
        private AutoResetEvent ev;

        /// <summary>
        /// As n example this operation accepts a workflow name and a param
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workflowName"></param>
        /// <param name="param"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool RunWorkflow(int workflowId, string param)
        {
            //create the blocking event.
            ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            //adde
            try
            {
                //using the workflow id lets determine soemhow which workflow you plan on running.
                //lets assume your storing the xaml file location (on disk) for each wf associated with an id
                //but in this scenario lets hardcode the location to the local C.
                var xamlPath = "C:/wf.xaml";

                //you can then envoke the xaml file.

                Activity workflow = ActivityXamlServices.Load(xamlPath);

                //create a dict to pass the param to our wf 
                // have to construct a dictionary
                //this has to be the same name as an InArgument<object> Argument on our xaml file.
                var input = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "paramName", param} };

                //create a medium to run the wf - force the syncronisation to be on the current thread which will mean one wf gets run at a time rather than multi threaded.
                var wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(workflow, input)
                {
                    Completed = e =>
                       {
                           if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Faulted)
                           {
                               //you could get the output from the wf
                           }
                           else if (e.CompletionState == ActivityInstanceState.Canceled)
                           {

                           }
                           ev.Set();
                       },
                    OnUnhandledException = e =>
                    {
                        //log error if you wanted to 
                        return UnhandledExceptionAction.Terminate;

                    },
                    SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
                };

                wfApp.Run();

                //wait for the wf to complete.
                ev.WaitOne();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log an error
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the following interface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFForWorkflowsExample
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool RunWorkflow(int workflowId, string param);
    }
}
```

Finally make sure that you have a xaml file that can be executed. Insuring that you have named the In argument correctly.

[image]

Once you have built, just copy the xaml file to the location of your choice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps a lot to get started. Thanks a lot :-)